# Testing if a string contains or startswith "no-value" ("")

Tags: python

Can anybody explain why, when testing if no-value ("") is contained within a string or if a string `startswith` no-value (""), the returned value is True.
As in:

```
>>> if "" in "L": print ("YES")
... 
YES
>>> if "" in " ": print ("YES")
... 
YES
>>> if "" in "abc": print ("YES")
... 
YES
>>> if "abc".startswith(""): print (True)
... 
True
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing
4.6.1. Common Sequence Operations

states

> x in s    True if an item of s is equal to x, else False

4.7.1. String Methods

> str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]]) Return True if string starts
>   with the prefix, otherwise return False.

I really want to know if I can rely on this behaviour as I came across
it with the following code:

```
sub_choices = [c for c in self.choices if Input_Text.casefold() in c.casefold()]
```

and

```
sub_choices = [c for c in self.choices if c.casefold().startswith(Input_Text.casefold())]
```

in this case if `Input_Text` was blank, sub_choices (by happy accident) was the entire contents of `self.choices`

Comment: Draw a parallel to set theory: the empty set is contained in every other set. `"" in x` and `x.startswith("")` are tautologies when `x` is a string.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079054/how-does-python-startswith-work

Comment: `your_string == "" + your_string` : that returns True.
So `your_string` must contain (and must start with) "".