# Count function counting ' '

Tags: python, string

I used `a="string"` to initialize a string in Python.  I then used `a.count('')`; I did not write anything inside the quotes (not even a space). The `count` function returned 7 in this case. I also tried with `a=str()` and then repeated the `count`and got 1. Can anyone please explain it to me?

Comment: Try doing `'' in 'string'` and see what you get. This should help explain the results you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a result of the comparison iteration, Python "finds" a null string at every interstice of the string.  In this case, you have 6 characters, so there are 6+1 interstices (start, end, and five between the letters).

Searching for a null string gets some results that are, at first, counter-intuitive.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think this question is a dupe. I can't seem to fine it googling though, and I can't remember the name.

Comment: I'm sure we've hit a subset of this somewhere, but couldn't find it with 5 minutes of search.  If someone finds it, I'll be happy to delete the answer, the question, ...

Comment: I know there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079054/how-does-python-startswith-work) similar question using `startswith` instead of `count`, but couldn't find another question