# discord.py returning empty string for every message

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, message

I am trying to make a discord bot with python with discord.py. The issue is that no matter the message being sent it returns to the program as an empty string.

main:

```
import discord
import os

#client = discord.Client()

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
      print('true event')
      await message.channel.send('Hello!')
      
    if message.content.startswith(''):
      print(message.content)
      print('empty string')
      await message.channel.send('Hello!')

try:
    client.run(os.getenv("key"))
except discord.HTTPException as e:
    if e.status == 429:
        print("The Discord servers denied the connection for making too many requests")
        print("Get help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66724687/in-discord-py-how-to-solve-the-error-for-toomanyrequests")
    else:
        raise e
```

After a massage it returns the empty string text in the terminal and Hello! in the server, but for message.content is always empty no matter what text is input on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this line of code `message.content.startswith('')` because it **will always** return `True` regardless of the message string. Here is a small example using a test message:

```
"message".startswith("")
True
```

If you want to check if your message is `empty`, you can do the following:

```
if not message.content:
```

[`Here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41079114/11286032) is a stack overflow answer that describes how `startswith()` works in `python`